# Offensive Language

Tags: discussion

How is the title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804823/networking-for-retard) [(screenshot <10K)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsYdF.png) not offensive? I flagged this as offensive, but the flag was declined as having no evidence.

The word "retard" may properly be used, in the correct context, as a verb, but when used as a noun, it is very insensitive, rude, offensive, and insulting.

Comment: *gets a snack, waits for meta effect*

Comment: well that was fast...

Comment: You're welcome @JustDoIt

Comment: I couldn't even get my snack :/ @rene and thanks ;)

Comment: "when used as a noun" - first definition - \ri-ˈtärd\ :  a holding back or slowing down from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retard

Comment: Edit would be more appropriate action - "XXXXX for dummies/for complete idiots" is very common title for books/articles, but may not be properly translated from other language back to English.

Comment: "Automotive, Machinery. an adjustment made in the setting of the distributor of an internal-combustion engine so that the spark for ignition in each cylinder is generated later in the cycle. " from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/retard

Comment: So it's not always offensive when used as a noun.

Comment: @DavidPostill, the definition to which you provide a link is for the verb, not for a noun. I stand by what I wrote.

Comment: @DavidPostill, the second link you provide shows the problem. In the context this was used it is "_Slang: Disparaging and Offensive._."

Comment: @RonMaupin Perhaps you should actually read the link I posted. Here is an image to make it clear for you. http://i.imgur.com/0zvTO4s.png. Can you see the bit at the top of the image that says **noun** ;)

Comment: @RonMaupin My point is not that it may be offensive. It is that it is not always offensive. It depends ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, that may say noun, but holding back or slowing down is a verb. The context was that the OP was using has nothing to do with that. The OP was using th offensive slang.

Comment: It's already been removed, but if the asker was calling themselves a retard, I'd edit it to the idiomatic "for dummies".  If the asker was calling someone else a retard, yes, that counts as offensive.

Comment: I don't see any harm in just editing it *in this case*. Was it offensive? Probably to some people, *but i doubt the OP intended it to be*. Just fix it and move on. If it's edited back in, *then* we have a problem.

Comment: We need SO dictionary:) Like "I have a doubt" as "I have a problem"...

Comment: Something like an attempt was made, @AlexeiLevenkov: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108425/159251

Comment: Ah... whoops. Not sure how I voted to close that without editing the title. Must have seen it in the review queue and just voted on it. FWIW, I think that usage *is* offensive, but I agree that it's better to just edit it out instead of flagging for someone else to do it.

Comment: The only thing more ridiculous that people being offended by certain words is people being offended by words that are not directed at them.  Also, everyone apparently forgot how to use the Edit link today.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I can totally see another audit failure coming your way...

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Well, except one person - who instead apparently forgot that he could edit out offensive terms.

Comment: @BoltClock, I tried the nice way first, with the comment, then I tried to edit, then I tried to flag as offensive, then I tried to flag for moderator intervention, then I posted this on meta. What else may I have done?

Comment: Oh, come on! I can't believe there are people seriously quoting the definition of "retard" from a dictionary. Yes, the word "retard" means to hinder or hold back. It does not, however, have the same literal meaning when applied to a *person*. "Retard network bandwidth" is a completely different title than "Networking for [a] retard." The former uses definition (1), the latter uses the vulgar definition (2). You may not be offended by the vulgar slang, but it is objectively offensive to many. Pretending that you don't see how just makes you look foolish, or worse, downright insensitive.

Comment: @Ron Maupin: Oh I wasn't referring to you - someone else edited the question but left the offensive word completely intact.

Comment: Apologies Ron, for the -10 you have received here. There is a socially conservative grouping on _Meta_ who don't care for people who are disadvantaged in one way or another.

Comment: @halfer, thank you. I really don't care about the voting, but I am appalled, not surprised, at the ignorance demonstrated in some of the comments. In any case, I accomplished in getting the question changed or removed, and that was my real goal. I did not, as has been suggested, blame or criticize the OP; I believe I was nothing but polite.

Comment: Agree - the casual usage of the word could do with reducing, but it's not as much of a problem as the view that people should be free to use the word _knowing_ it will offend. But, slow steps - despite regressive barriers, society is moving in the right direction. See where we have come from in the last decade, on disability, sexuality and gender - take heart!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think he was actually trying to be insulting. Self-deprecating, perhaps. You may not like the word - I don't - but it's commonly used in this sense without being targeted at the developmentally-disabled.

Next time, please just edit out the term. Flag *if* the author gets obstinate about such an edit.

Note that the question is now deleted.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the OP to be self-deprecating by using the n-word instead of the r-word? Both are equally offensive words.

Comment: @RonMaupin how often do you see that being used in the real world? That those two terms are *equally* offensive is very arguable. I agree, the word could simply have been edited out

Comment: I didn't say it was acceptable, @Ron. I said you should get rid of it. You have the ability to put the change you wish to see into action, why depend on someone else to do it for you?

Comment: I attempted to get it corrected, several times, in several ways. I finally brought it up here, and now it is gone.

Comment: @RonMaupin just make a joke in language that is not your native language... It is *very* hard to sense the boundaries of what is acceptable. (And it is somewhat why SO does not welcome jokes). OP clearly identify themselves as non-native-speaker with they name - while attempting to make a joke in title is questionable translating "networking for dummies" to non-English and back to English could easily results in the title of the post.... (just reasoning why it could have happen, not that I endorse such usage)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, That is one reason, I politely pointed out that it was offensive and asked the OP to change it. Also, that name wouldn't necessarily suggest a non-English speaker in the U.S. (great melting pot).

Comment: @Pekka웃, I'm not sure I understand your comment, but real-world usage of ether word is also unacceptable, even though I do occasionally hear both.

Comment: @RonMaupin I don't think whether or not it's used real-world is what's important. ***Intent*** is. but even then... if you replaced what he used with something else, like a generalized slang for a certain population of people, the initial action should still be the same. edit it out.

Comment: @Ron Maupin: I only see one way you attempted to get it corrected prior to your meta post - and that was in a comment. You didn't suggest an edit yourself, for example.

Comment: @BoltClock, I did propose an edit, and I flagged for offensive, and I flagged for moderator intervention. This was over a period of several days, and all my attempts were rejected.

Comment: @Ron Maupin: Oh right, the post is deleted... that explains why I wouldn't have seen your edit in your [activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3745413/ron-maupin?tab=activity). Now I have no idea how to get to your edit proposal, and I don't imagine you have a link handy either :S

Comment: *"it's commonly used in this sense without being targeted at the developmentally-disabled"* Citation required. Obviously we cannot judge the author's intent, and in this case it may have been pure, but all that means is he doesn't know how offensive the word is. I totally agree with the rest of this answer, but that phrase bristles. This isn't a word that you can just choose to like or dislike. Words have power, and this one packs a punch.

Comment: *Would it be acceptable for the OP to be self-deprecating by using the n-word instead of the r-word?* Apparently ***somebody*** doesn't listen to rap.